# Data storage after API call form Postman/SoapUI

Tags: api, rest, web-services, postman, soapui

I need to create an automated test-setup for some webservies, and plan to use SoapUI or Postman for that. My question is pretty basic. What happnds to the data after a request is made?

E.g. if the response contains data from a system, and display it in the Postman UI, will Postman store the response? Or what will happnd to it after the request?

I'm asking for security purpose and I was not able to find a concrete answer myself. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official site

**"[Postman does not track any content of your requests/responses.](https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/203815791-What-usage-data-does-Postman-collect-)"**

Under **File--> settings**

[image]

You can even avoid using the cloud version if you don't want to sync up things

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Postman provides us the explicit ways to store data or not. When you try to run a collection then in the settings we can specify if we want to store responses, cookies, etc or not. Configure it as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

Re SoapUI...
If you call a service once, then the data remains in the UI.  If you run a second or third time, then only the last response is shown in he UI.

Once you close SoapUI, the request and response data is gone.

However, you can save the data from every request and response by using a datasink step, should that be what you want.